# Can't create a S3 bucket with KMS_MANAGED key and bucketKeyEneabled via CDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

I have a S3 bucket with this configuration:

[image: S3 Bucket default encryption settings]

I'm trying to create a bucket with this same configuration via CDK:

```
Bucket.Builder.create(this, "test1")
  .bucketName("com.myorg.test1")
  .encryption(BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED)
  .bucketKeyEnabled(true)
  .build()
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: bucketKeyEnabled is specified, so 'encryption' must be set to KMS (value: MANAGED)

This seems like a bug to me, but I'm relatively new to CDK so I'm not sure. Am I doing something wrong, or is this indeed a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the issue recently, and I have found the answer. I want to share the findings here just in case anyone gets stuck.

Yes, this was a bug in the AWS-CDK. The fix was merged this month: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/22331

According to the CDK doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#bucketkeyenabled), if `bucketKeyEnabled` is set to `true`, S3 will use its own time-limited key instead, which helps reduce the cost (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-key.html); it's only relevant when Encryption is set to `BucketEncryption.KMS` or `BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED`.

Answer (score -1):

bucketKeyEnabled flag , straight from docs:

> Specifies whether Amazon S3 should use an S3 Bucket Key with
> server-side encryption using KMS (SSE-KMS)

BucketEncryption has 4 options.

> NONE - no encryption

> MANAGED - Kms key managed by AWS

> S3MANAGED - Key managed by S3

> KMS - key managed by user, a new KMS key will be created.

we don't need to set bucketKeyEnabled at all for any scenario. In this case, all we need is aws/s3 , so,

bucketKeyEnabled: Need not be set.(since this is only for SSE-KMS)

encryption: Should be set to BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED

Example:

```
const buck = new s3.Bucket(this, "my-bucket", {
  bucketName: "my-test-bucket-1234",
  encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ BaluVyamajala, but I am not interested in using a SSE-S3 key. I'm looking to use an AWS managed SSE-KMS key *and* a S3 bucket key for cost reduction.

Comment: SSE-S3 is the cheapest and most basic option to have S3 data encryption at rest.  SSE-KMS meaning to have a KMS key managed by AWS and will give us more control on permissions and all, will need to pay extra.

Comment: @TimPesce even for SSE-KMS, we don't need to set bucketKeyEnabled flag at all, all we need to set is `BucketEncryption` as KMS_MANAGED

Comment: Thank you for the additional answers, but I'm not sure you understand the question. I'm not looking for suggestions on how to configure encryption for my bucket, I have a specific configuration that I am trying to achieve via CDK that is not working.

Comment: i just added a sample code i tested with a screen shot of how it created the bucket, this is exact same as the screen shot in question. we don't need to use `bucketKeyEnabled` is all I am trying to say.